# Generate Each number between 2 numbers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure out a way to generate each number between 2 other numbers. For example, if the first number is 7 and the last number is 12 I want to generate an array(?) of Int that would be `Intarray {7,8,9,10,11,12}.`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Enumerable.Range(,)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range) will be your friend.